# Modo Oscuro en Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una duda, tengo un textarea

```
<textarea id="textareaComentarioAdicionalServicios" class="form-control textareaComentarios" 
style="height: 95px;"></textarea>
```

Este por defecto es color blanco, con efecto de borde y esas cosas por defecto, entonces le agregue modo oscuro a la página web y funciona a como deseaba si cliqueo sobre el boton para cambiar a modo oscuro funciona, el textarea se pone oscuro, pero al momento de seleccionarlo y escribir en el, este se vuelve blanco o modo light por así decirlo ¿Alguien sabe como evitar eso, decir que se quede en modo oscuro aun editando en él?

Código Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: #17A2B8; border-color: solid 1px #17A2B8; 
color: white;" onclick="cambiarModo()">Modo Oscuro</button>
```

Código JS

```
function cambiarModo(){
   var textareaComentarioAdicionalServicios = 
   document.getElementById("textareaComentarioAdicionalServicios");
   textareaComentarioAdicionalServicios.classList.toggle("oscuroInput");
}
```

Código CSS

```
.oscuroInput{
transition: .40s;
background: #202020;
}
```

Alguien puede explcarme porfavor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eso ocurre porque Bootstrap le agrega un color de fondo a los input que están seleccionados (focus) entonces, para que tu código funcione como quieres, solo debes modificar tu css y agregarle

```
.oscuroInput, .oscuroInput:focus{
    transition: .40s;
    background: #202020;
}
```

solo asegúrate que este css este después del tag que carga el .css de Bootstrap, de lo contrario Bootstrap te lo podría pisar.
saludos!

Comment: Jhonnattan Rivera, muchisimas gracias ¡Si funciono!